# Variables not parsing in commands

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a windows cmd batch file that uses a variable, but everywhere that variable is used after setting it is failing.

Here is my batch script:

```
@echo off

if exist Transactions.csv (
    set datestr=%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
    rename Transactions.csv Transactions-%datestr%.csv
    curl -s -o curl.log --form upload=@Transactions-%datestr%.csv http://192.168.5.217/test_upload.php
    set datestr=
)
```

The file gets renamed to "Transactions-.csv", and the curl command works OK because it's sending the file as is, but I'd like it to properly rename the file.

If I comment out the echo off line, this is what I get back:

```
if exist Transactions.csv (
    set datestr=20112206112720
    rename Transactions.csv Transactions-.csv
    curl -s -o curl.log --form upload=@Transactions-.csv http://192.168.5.217/test_upload.php
    set datestr=
)
```

Note the missing areas where %datestr% should be.

Any ideas why these variables are not properly being parsed?

Comment: Found my solution after trial and error.  Variables only get parsed once while inside conditionals.  I moved my SET commands outside the IF statement and it all worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a block of commands enclosed in parentheses, the entire block is parsed before its first command executes. That means, all the `%var%` expressions inside that block are replaced with their values *at that time*. That's why you could see nothing in place of `%datestr%` when you ran the script with `@echo off` commented out.

So your decision to move the body of the IF statement outside the brackets was right.

Another solution to that would be to use delayed expansion:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if exist Transactions.csv (
    set datestr=!date:~10,4!!date:~7,2!!date:~4,2!!time:~0,2!!time:~3,2!time:~6,2!
    rename Transactions.csv Transactions-!datestr!.csv
    curl -s -o curl.log --form upload=@Transactions-!datestr!.csv http://192.168.5.217/test_upload.php
    set datestr=
)
```

As you can see, the delayed expansion mode is introduced with the `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` command. Note also the change of syntax: `!` instead of `%` denote the delayed expansion of the corresponding variable/expression. When delayed expansion is enabled, you can still use `%` for immediate expansion, where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this way of parsing the date depends heavily in the locale used.
`%DATE%` returns the current date using the short date format that is fully (endlessly) customizable. One user may configure its system to return Fri040811 and another user may choose 08/04/2011... it's a complete nightmare for a BAT programmer.

There are two solutions to this problem.

Solution 1, change temporarily the locale.

```
reg copy "HKCU\Control Panel\International" "HKCU\Control Panel\International-Temp" /f >nul
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate /d "yyyy-MM-dd" /f >nul
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sTimeFormat /d "HH:mm:ss" /f >nul
```

do your %DATE% logic, for example

```
set datestr=%date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
ren test.txt test-%datestr%.txt
```

and then restore the locale back

```
reg copy "HKCU\Control Panel\International-Temp" "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /f >nul
```

Solution 2. use WMIC.

```
WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day,Hour,Minute,Month,Second,Year /Format:table
```

returns the date in a convenient way to directly parse it with a FOR.

Comment: While the real issue for my original question was due to the variables only being parsed once inside the brackets, I appreciate you giving me this further information, and will incorporate this into my batch script and hopefully make it work more consistently.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I create a batch file with the following content:

```
@echo off
set datestr=%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
echo Transactions.csv Transactions-%datestr%.csv
set datestr=
```

It shows:

```
C:\Temp>test
Transactions.csv Transactions-012/133612.csv
```

This shows me that what's actually causing the failure is the `datestr` formatting you've selected - the date value contains a forward slash, which isn't valid in a filename, and this is causing the `rename` to fail. (It's got to be the values you're using in parsing the date output; you've got an off-by-one error.)

You're not seeing it in your hard-coded test because you've hard-coded the properly formatted date instead of what you're getting in `datestr`.

Comment: I tested all my date strings, and on my system (Windows Vista), the output of the variable is valid:
`
C:\>echo %datestr%
20112206111637
`

Comment: You must be set to a different locale or something than I am. I tested on XP and Win7 with the same results, but mine are both set to US locale. Glad you got it worked out. :)

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code into a .cmd script and ran it and it successfully renamed the file. However, rather than nesting in parenthesis I did a GoTo block reference and wrapped the datestr concatenation inside of double-quotes. Here's the code I used...

```
@echo off
if exist test.txt (
    goto RENFILE
) else (
    goto NOTFOUND
)

:RENFILE
set datestr="%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%"
echo %datestr%
rename test.txt test-%datestr%.txt
goto END

:NOTFOUND
echo file not found!
goto END

:END
pause
```

Comment: The result was that my example renamed "test.txt" to "test-20112206134545.txt"  There were no other characters inserted.